# Import order theming bootstrap in Angular CLI

Tags: angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I'm having some issues on trying to create a custom theme for bootstrap in Angular Cli.

In my `styles.scss` I have this:

```
@import "scss/_theme.scss";  
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

In `scss/_theme.scss` I have this:

```
$theme-colors: (
    "primary": #ff0000
);

body {
    font-family: 'Times New Roman'
}
```

So, I'm trying to override the primary color variable and, also, the font-family of the body.

For some reason I'm getting this:

[image: Example 1]

As you can see, the primary color is the correct one (#ff0000) but the font family is not "Times New Roman", it's the default font family of bootstrap.

Anyway, if I change the order of the imports like this (bootstrap first):

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "scss/_theme.scss";
```

I've got this different scenario:

[image: Example 2]

So, the font family attribute is being replaced for "Times New Roman", but now it's using the default primary color of bootstrap and ignoring my override.

By the way, I obviously want both changes to take place at the same time.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding bootstrap in two different ways. For color you are (correctly) using sass variable and for font you are directly setting css property. Because sass variables should be declared first and then bootstrap imported, your scenario A is working as expected for fonts. But because later declared css property is more important, your scenario B is working for body fonts. I suggest you switch font via sass variable $font-family-base or $font-family-sans-serif and include your theme file first like you did in first example.

See available variables [in bootstrap source code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/09ae92a0a097fd3b90108d6c7363dccdd32f5888/scss/_variables.scss).